# Django: check if value in values_list with & without prefetch_related/select_related

Tags: python, django, list, orm

I've observed this behavior and I don't quite understand.  Let say I make a query:

```
result = model.objects.all()
result_pks = result.values_list("id",flat=True)
print result_pks
```

And I get:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Then I want to check if a certain value is in the list of pks returned:

```
val = 2
print val in result_pks
```

This will return True, but if instead I change result to:

```
result = model.objects.prefetch_related("related_field").all()
result_pks = result.values_list("id",flat=True)
print result_pks
```

I still get:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

But when I do:

```
val=2
print val in result_pks
```

I get False. I tried using select_related instead, and that returned True as I expected. Can someone explain to me why the difference?

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using Django 1.5?

There was a bug that caused the `in` lookup to fail when using `prefetch_related`: [bug 20242](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20242).

This has been fixed in Django 1.6.

Comment: So, the fix could be `print val in list(result_pks)`

Comment: Thanks. I am using 1.4 because of GAE

Comment: @CoffeeJack: not sure when the bug was introduced but it may well be in Django 1.4 too.